# What is the $n$-th power of a square matrix?

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

How can I determine the $n$-th value of a square matrix contaning only positive integers?

Comment: Multiply it by itself $n$ times.

Comment: You could use this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix if you know the eigenvalues

Comment: Use the Jordan decomposition.